# What does the L option of SSH do?

Tags: ssh, vnc, localhost

To make VNC secure, I am supposed to use this

```
ssh -L 5901:127.0.0.1:5901 user@example.com
```

from the client. Use 5901 if the server display is 1; use 5900 for display 0. This command was taken from a [tutorial](https://www.linode.com/docs/applications/remote-desktop/install-vnc-on-ubuntu-16-04).

The description of the option is

```
-L [bind_address:]port:host:hostport

             Specifies that the given port on the local (client) host is to be
             forwarded to the given host and port on the remote side.  This
             works by allocating a socket to listen to port on the local side,
             optionally bound to the specified bind_address.  Whenever a
             connection is made to this port, the connection is forwarded over
             the secure channel, and a connection is made to host port
             hostport from the remote machine.  Port forwardings can also be
             specified in the configuration file.  IPv6 addresses can be
             specified with an alternative syntax:
             [bind_address/]port/host/hostport or by enclosing the address in
             square brackets.  Only the superuser can forward privileged
             ports.  By default, the local port is bound in accordance with
             the GatewayPorts setting.  However, an explicit bind_address may
             be used to bind the connection to a specific address.  The
             bind_address of “localhost” indicates that the listening port be
             bound for local use only, while an empty address or ‘*’ indicates
             that the port should be available from all interfaces.
```

The [ssh_config files description](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ssh_config&sektion=5) includes this

```
GatewayPorts
         Specifies whether remote hosts are allowed to connect to local
         forwarded ports.  By default, ssh(1) binds local port forwardings
         to the loopback address.  This prevents other remote hosts from
         connecting to forwarded ports.  GatewayPorts can be used to spec-
         ify that ssh should bind local port forwardings to the wildcard
         address, thus allowing remote hosts to connect to forwarded
         ports.  The argument must be ``yes'' or ``no''.  The default is
         ``no''.
```

Please explain this command or diagram it.

Answer (score 1):

This is simply a way to apply well-tested security to the insecure VNC protocol. SSH is widely used, it has well-tested encryption protocols, and it supports a variety of authentication protocols. VNC is just widely used, and not as much as SSH.

The L option of SSH forwards traffic from the local system to the remote system, under SSH's protection. So, where VNC isn't secure or flexible enough by itself, by forwarding VNC traffic over SSH, you get the full power of SSH for protecting it.

By forwarding your localhost's port to the remote host, you ensure that none of your unencrypted VNC traffic is leaked on the local (or remote, for that matter) networks.
To intercept any of this, an attacker will have to break SSH, or have root access to the systems involved, in which case you have already lost.

Comment: I know that. The first 4 words of the question are: "to make VNC secure". How about explaining the '[number:]number:localhost:number' thing.

Comment: @H2ONaCl that's explained in the manual. What part of that do you not understand?

Comment: May be the manual needs a diagram.

Comment: @H2ONaCl http://dirk-loss.de/ssh-port-forwarding.htm

Comment: Note to self: at the  link SSHD does not mean solid state hybrid drive. It probably means SSH daemon.

Comment: The author says the learning should start with 4 systems but he seems to illustrate 3 systems. ???

Comment: @H2ONaClas he says, `port:host:port` is a shorthand which omits the host on the local side - if that's included, there would be four IP addresses in play - the IP address where SSH will be listening for the traffic to be forward, the IP address the local system presents to the remote server, the remote server's IP address for SSH to connect to, the  IP address where the traffic is forwarded to on the remote side. All four could be distinct, and all four could be the same (and you could think of them as "systems")

Comment: In my answer, my ASCII diagram has 4 hosts, so it might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Basically this makes the port 5902 on example.com accessible as it was running on your local machine

```
ssh -L 5901:127.0.0.1:5902 user@example.com
```

After running this command you can access what is running on example.com:5902 on your local machine 127.0.0.1:5901

user@example.com - user/server you are connecting to

5902 - the target port you want forward

5901 - the port number the target port should be reachable on

Comment: So this is not a mistake? You want to illustrate with port 5902 rather than 5901 in both places?

Comment: I changed it to two different ports to better explain it. In this scenarie you bind the port 5902 on example.com to be reachable on 127.0.0.1:5901. They can be the same port (often they are)

Comment: What does 127.0.0.1 mean? Localhost of the client or localhost of the server?

Comment: @H2ONaCl late but: 127.0.0.1 always refers to the localhost (on the host the command is entered on)

Answer (score 1):

SSH normally provides a remote shell accessible securely at a local terminal. The command with the `-L` option appears to offer the secure tunnel capability to ports at the two ends.

Suppose the command is

`ssh -L 5901:127.0.0.1:5901 user@remoteIP`

In the above option there are two instances of `5901`.

In the above option the first instance of `5901` determines the configuration on the machine that is the LOCAL HOST, which is not to say "localhost". The LOCAL HOST is the machine executing the `ssh` command. In the above option the remainder of the string, `127.0.0.1:5901`, determines the configuration on the machine that is the REMOTE HOST at `remoteIP`.

An application on the REMOTE HOST can access the secure tunnel via 127.0.0.1:5901 where the 127.0.0.1 is explicit so only an application on the same machine will be allowed to access the tunnel.

An application on the LOCAL HOST can access the secure tunnel via 127.0.0.1:5901 where the 127.0.0.1 is by default. If GatewayPorts is 'yes' then a `*` can be specified in the option to mean any host (with any IP) may access the secure tunnel. The form of the command would then be

`ssh -L *:5901:127.0.0.1:5901 user@remoteIP`

An illustration with 4 hosts:

```
App Host A <---> Host Running `ssh` <---> Host At `remoteIP` <---> App Host B
```

App Host A could be on the same machine as the Host Running `ssh`.

App Host B could be on the same machine as the Host at `remoteIP`.

Addendum 0: Note that this command makes it appear that port 5901 is being used but in fact the tunnel is the substitute for port 5901 on both ends. Thus you can disable port 5901. In fact if no others are needed you can disable all ports except the one being used by `ssh` which is by convention 22.

Addendum 1: Lately I noticed that when issuing the command 
`ssh -L 5901:127.0.0.1:5901 user@remoteIP`
where the REMOTE HOST `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` has no `GatewayPorts` value, the LOCAL HOST reports the following error: "bind: Cannot assign requested address". The tunnel works even though an error was generated. When `GatewayPorts` has no value it defaults to `no`. It would seem the value `no` is more secure so I want to keep it that way. The error message is one that I cannot explain. I now issue the following command which avoids generating the error message.
`ssh -L 127.0.0.1:5901:127.0.0.1:5901 user@remoteIP`

Comment: This is the answer that explained all to me. Well, and [this link](https://www.bitvise.com/port-forwarding). But I think your addendum is wrong. You actually need your port 5901 on your Client for this to work.

Comment: @JohnRed Yes, you need port 5901 because it is being used in the terms of the command but when I say you can "disable" 5901 what I mean is that your firewall does not need to enable 5901 because the traffic of ssh actually passes through port 22 by convention. I think of 5901 as just a label for the two ends of the tunnel.

Answer (score 0):

I find this confusing because of the use of "localhost" in many examples.

LocalPort:RemoteHost:RemotePort user@IntermediateHost

LocalPort: This is a local port that SSH opens on the machine that you run the ssh command. You will typically setup your client machine to connect to localhost:5901 - on your client machine.

RemoteHost: This is the target machine, to which a connection is attempted - from the IntermediateHost machine. I.e. it is relative to the RemoteHost. When you use "localhost" here, it means "IntermediateHost".

RemotePort: This is the target port on the target machine

IntermediateHost: This is the machine listening (by default, on SSH port 22) that the ssh command connects to. It is this machine that attempts to connect to RemoteHost:RemoteHost.

In the oft-quoted example of secure VNC / SSH tunnel:

```
ssh -L 5901:localhost:5900 myuser@IntermediateHost
```

The "localhost" here is relative to IntermediateHost, i.e. it IS IntermediateHost.

Local port 5901 is opened, so you can configure your local VNC client to connect to port 5901 on the local machine. Confusingly this is referred to as: "localhost:5901".

In the parameter, "localhost:5900" is the target to which the IntermediateHost connects: therefore it connects to itself.

Hence the ssh server running on IntermediateHost is instructed to send all traffic to "localhost:5900" - i.e. to itself. The traffic comes from what is sent to port 5901 on the local client machine.

Hope this helps

Comment: In my answer I avoided the confusing term "localhost" by calling it LOCAL HOST to distinguish it from REMOTE HOST. I think using the same port number on both sides (for example 5901) makes it more obvious that the host IP, whether explicit or assumed, provides disambiguation so you do not need to use two different port numbers. Using two port numbers is ironically more confusing, in my opinion.